# C# How to stop selecting an item from list box

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox, selecteditem

quick question: When I click anywhere on the list box (Not clicking on the items) it automatically selects the first item, how can I remove this? I want the user to select a specific item.

Thanks!

Code:

```
        private void FriendsLb_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var obj = FriendsLb.SelectedItem;
        if (obj != null)
        {
            FriendsLb.MouseDown += FriendsLb_MouseDown;
        }
    }
    private void FriendsLb_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            var item = FriendsLb.IndexFromPoint(e.Location);
            if (item >= 0)
            {
                try {
                    FriendsLb.SelectedIndex = item;
                    userRightClick.Show(FriendsLb, e.Location);
                }
                catch { return; } // No item selected
            }
        }
```

Comment: You can use the `SelectedIndex` Property of listbox 

`listbox1.selectedindex = 0`

Comment: selectedIndex = 0 will select the first item, he doesn't want that ^^

Comment: selected index of negative one will un-select.

Comment: SelectedIndexChanged event can solve your problem. If you click anywhere on listbox without clicking on items, it will return **-1**.

Comment: Does it do that automatically or do I have to do it?

Comment: When you click on an area without items, nothing happens. Previous selected item remain untouched by default. Also when you execute the current code, it sets the item at mouse position as selected item and shows a context menu. It doesn't change the selected index when you click on an area without any items. It's unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Clicking on the white space of the ListBox does not select the first item in the list for me.  You should only add an event handler once: you are adding it for every click so that the MouseDown code ends up running multiple times.